# How to calculate euclidean distance if given Conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample of companies with financial figures which I would like to compare. My data looks like this:

```
    Cusip9      Issuer                       IPO Year   Total Assets    Long-Term Debt  Sales      SIC-Code
1   783755101   Ryerson Tull Inc                1996    9322000.0        2632000.0      633000.0   3661
2   826170102   Siebel Sys Inc                  1996    995010.0         0.0            50250.0    2456
3   894363100   Travis Boats & Motors Inc       1996    313500.0         43340.0        23830.0    3661
4   159186105   Channell Commercial Corp        1996    426580.0         3380.0         111100.0   7483
5   742580103   Printware Inc                   1996    145750.0         0.0            23830.0    8473
```

For every company I want to calculate a "similarity Score". This score should indicate the comparability with other companies. Therefore I want to compare them in different financial figures. The comparability should be expressed as the euclidean distance, the square root of the sum of the squared differences between the financial figures, to the "closest company". So I need to calculate the distance to every company, that fits these conditions, but only need the closest score. Assets of Company 1 minus Assets of Company 2 plus Debt Company 1 minus Debt Comapny 2....

```
√((x_1-y_1 )^2+(x_2-y_2 )^2)
```

This should only be computed for companies with the same SIC-Code and the IPO Year of the comparable companies should be smaller then for the company for which the "Similarity score" is computed. I only want to compare these companies with already listed companies.

Hopefully, my point get's clear. Has someone any idea where I can start? I am just starting with programming and completely lost with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start by cleaning your data and throwing out the companies you don't want to compare. Then, just compute the Euclidian distance using the traits you have selected. I would strongly agree to standardize or normalize the numbers, first. As the scales are very different, your ED will be dominated by the difference along the dimension with the largest scale (total assets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated the data you provided and then calculated the distances. For each issuer I find the closest issuer and its distance. See modified code below. Please let me know if you need more details.

```
issuers = ["Ryerson Tull Inc", "Siebel Sys Inc", "Travis Boats & Motors Inc", "Channell Commercial Corp", "Printware Inc",
           "AAA", "BBB", "ZZZ"]
ttl_assets = [9322000.0, 995010.0, 313500.0, 426580.0, 145750.0, 299999.0, 399999.0, 123456.0]
long_term_debt = [2632000.0, 0.0, 43340.0, 3380.0, 0.0, 11111.0, 22222.0, 87500.0]
sic_code = [3661, 2456, 3661, 7483, 8473, 3661, 7483, 3661]
ipo_year = [1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1997]

data = pd.DataFrame({"issuer": issuers, 
                     "total assets": ttl_assets, 
                     "long term debt": long_term_debt,
                     "SIC-Code": sic_code,
                     "IPO Year": ipo_year
                    })

def get_distance(x1, x2):
    """ computes euclidean distance between two points """
    d = math.sqrt((x1[0] - x2[0])**2 + (x1[1] - x2[1])**2)
    return round(d, 3)

distMatrix = np.ndarray(shape=(len(data), len(data))) # creating an array to fill up the distances
distMatrix[:, :] = np.inf

for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data)):
        if data.loc[i, "SIC-Code"] == data.loc[j, "SIC-Code"] and data.loc[i, "IPO Year"] == data.loc[j, "IPO Year"] and i != j:
            issuer1 = data.loc[i, ["total assets", "long term debt"]].values
            issuer2 = data.loc[j, ["total assets", "long term debt"]].values
            distance = get_distance(issuer1, issuer2)
            distMatrix[i, j] = distance


listIssuers = data["issuer"].tolist()
arrMinDist = distMatrix.argmin(axis=0)
dictMinDistIssuer = {} # dictionary that maps each issuer to its closest issuer
dictMinDist = {} # maps each each issuer to the closest issuers distance

dfDist = pd.DataFrame(distMatrix.tolist())
dfDist.columns = listIssuers
dfDist.insert(0, "issuer", listIssuers)
dfDist.insert(1, "IPO Year", ipo_year)
dfDist.insert(2, "SIC-Code", sic_code)

for issuer_idx, min_idx in enumerate(arrMinDist):
    distance_value_counts = np.where(distMatrix==np.inf, 0, 1).sum(axis=0) # this checks if there are any matches for each issuer
    if distance_value_counts[issuer_idx] == 0:
        dictMinDistIssuer[listIssuers[issuer_idx]] = np.nan
        dictMinDist[listIssuers[issuer_idx]] = np.nan
    else:
        dictMinDistIssuer[listIssuers[issuer_idx]] = listIssuers[min_idx]
        dictMinDist[listIssuers[issuer_idx]] = distMatrix[issuer_idx][min_idx]
    
dfDist["closest issuer"] = dfDist["issuer"].map(dictMinDistIssuer)
dfDist["closest issuer dist"] = dfDist["issuer"].map(dictMinDist)
dfDist.replace(to_replace=np.inf, value=np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Comment: thanks. Sorry, but I forgot to mention that I only want the closest score. I edited my question. For a better understanding, why do you rebuild the Dataframe? I just tried your code and It works perfectly, but as I said I only want the closest score. Do you have any idea how to adapt it?

Comment: griggy, looks already pretty good. Now the last thing I would need, is do you see any way to take the SIC-Code into account?

Comment: smnlscae. I updated the code and made some changes to the previously posted code. I believe it should work as you expect it. If not, let me know. I added some simulated data for testing. Run on a larger data and see if it does what you expect.

Comment: Do you also have an idea how to calculate the distance between two dataframes? In the code above the IPO companies are only compared with the other IPO companies. It would also be interesting to compare the IPO companies with other companies for different years. @griggy

Comment: Hi smnlscae. In the code that I shared if you update the if statement, from if data.loc[i, "SIC-Code"] == data.loc[j, "SIC-Code"] and data.loc[i, "IPO Year"] == data.loc[j, "IPO Year"] and i != j to if i != j it may do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Consider self-joining the data frame with itself for all possible pairings by `SIC-Code` and lesser `IPO-Year`. Be sure to also avoid reverse duplicates. Then run simple, vectorized arithmetic calculation across the columns using [Numpy math](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.math.html) and [Series operations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html). No loop needed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
...

# REMOVE SPACES AND HYPHENS IN COLUMNS
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'[ -]', '_')
             
# SELF JOIN AND AVOID REVERSE DUPLICATES WITH LESSER YEAR
df = (df.merge(df, on=['SIC-Code'])
        .query("(Cusip9_x < Cusip9_y) & (Issuer_x < Issuer_y) & (IPO_Year_x < IPO_Year_y)")
     )

# SIMILARITY SCORE CALCULATION
df['similarity_score'] = np.sqrt((df['Total_Assets_x'] - df['Total_Assets_y']).pow(2) +
                                 (df['Long_Term_Debt_x'] - df['Long_Term_Debt_y']).pow(2))
```